# How to Return Location of a Specific Value Between Two Locations in a Data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to write a code which will return all locations of a specific value between two ranges within a data frame.
To explain it further, lets suppose, I have **0** in a data frame, which has **50** rows from **1:36**. Suppose want a solution which would only look between rows **12:36** and return the location of number of zeros.

The data frame I am working with is given below:

```
structure(list(`Key Figures` = c("Jan-19", "Feb-19", "Mar-19", 
"Apr-19", "May-19", "Jun-19", "Jul-19", "Aug-19", "Sep-19", "Oct-19", 
"Nov-19", "Dec-19", "Jan-20", "Feb-20", "Mar-20", "Apr-20", "May-20", 
"Jun-20", "Jul-20", "Aug-20", "Sep-20", "Oct-20", "Nov-20", "Dec-20", 
"Jan-21", "Feb-21", "Mar-21", "Apr-21", "May-21", "Jun-21", "Jul-21", 
"Aug-21", "Sep-21", "Oct-21", "Nov-21", "Dec-21"), SKU = c("XYZ_20645", 
"XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", 
"XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", 
"XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", 
"XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", 
"XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", 
"XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", 
"XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645", "XYZ_20645"
), `Baseline history Q` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 10, 
10, 0, 100, 0, 30, 0, 50, 70, 280)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code I wrote is given below:

```
Pd <- read_excel("X:/X/X/X- X/X/X.xlsx",
                             sheet = "X")

Start_Location <- head(which(Pd$`Baseline history Q`!=0),1)
End_Location <- tail(which(Pd$`Baseline history Q`!=0),1)

which(Pd$`Baseline history Q`!=0)
```

The `which()` function return all the non zero values and the location but I am not sure how to make it within the range `Start_location : End_Location`. Sharing the Location as shown below:

```
print(Start_Location)
[1] 12
print(End_Location)
[1] 36
```

The Expected output is the locations which has 0 in it as shown here:

[image]

Can someone help me out and let me know, how to do it correctly?

Comment: Is another way to phrase this "How do I count how many zeroes are in a column between the first and last non-zeroes?"

Comment: For the position of the zeros in `x` between the first and last nonzero, try `r <- range(which(x != 0)); which(!x[(r[1] + 1):(r[2] - 1)]) + r[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do?

```r
Pd <- data.frame(`Baseline history Q` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                          10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 10, 
                                          10, 0, 100, 0, 30, 0, 50, 70, 280), check.names = FALSE)

(start_z <- head(which(Pd$`Baseline history Q`!=0),1))
#> [1] 12
(end_z   <- tail(which(Pd$`Baseline history Q`!=0),1))
#> [1] 36


which_z <- which(Pd$`Baseline history Q` == 0)
which_z[which_z %in% start_z:end_z]
#> [1] 26 29 31 33
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The Row reference cant be hard coded as this changed from one column to another column, this was shared as an example to convey the need. Would it work if I wrote the code using Start_Location and End_Location. 
`which_z[which_z %in% Start_Location:End_Location]`. Would it work?

Comment: @user20203146, it would.